# Firebase Realtime Database in Angular: How to add values

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database set up and I want to use angular to add values to it. Can someone please tell me how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Sure, show what code you have now and what you're having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire is mostly focused on simplifying how to **show** value *from* Firebase in an Angular UI. To write values **to** the database simply use the syntax as shown in the regular documentation for the JavaScript SDK for [writing a single value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write), and [adding data to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Since AngularFire is built on top of this JavaScript SDK, they interoperate perfectly and it will show those values right away.